# Prevent an attacker getting usernames of a system

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, security

We have a security issue on our forgot password page that was flagged as this:

> ISS-0003938   Web Inspect Open    Medium  Suspicious Files Found in
>   Recursive Directory ****** Remove any unnecessary pages from the web
>   server If any files are necessary restrict access to those that are
>   not supposed to be publicly accessible Remove any backup files and
>   temporary files that were on the server for development testing Please
>   remove backup files alternative login files, files that contain
>   functionality that are depreciated and any short cut files that
>   developers use.

The file that was flagged is `/js/pmailer_minimal.js` the reason because there is the following in the `.js` file.

```
url: URL + '/login/forgot-password/request/'+ username,
```

By using that information attackers are then able to start enumerating usernames until they get a success message from the response.

What would the best solution to this issue be? Do we change our response? Do we limit the amount of retries? What other solutions are there?

What should also be taken into consideration is that should an attacker have a username, he can attempt a brute force attack.

I'm looking for as many suggestions to solve this threat as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add a pentester perspective to this.

It's pretty easy to get a list of people for a company. Just google LinkedIn, etc. I make even have some potential passwords (password dumps, stupid passwords like Pa$$w0rd, the company name or other common patterns).

The issue is applying those to a random webapp that's exposed. Is the username format like first.lastname, email, firstinitiallastname or something else. I'll take those and try all users with a few potential passwords. The goal is to get ONE valid login. Then it's easy to pull the full list of real users from the app itself.

Giving a generic answer on a login page really frustrates our efforts. If I can get the correct username, I can try up to about 24 passwords per user (one password across every user every hour, to try and avoid lockouts). There's not many organizations where I haven't gotten a successful login within a day of trying.

If I can't determine if the username is correct, then I have to try every combination of usernames for every potential password. So I might only get to try 3-4 passwords for each potential user before it becomes too much effort. So unless users pick REALLY stupid passwords, I'm probably not gonna get in the app.

Sometimes you can check usernames against other parts of the app, the password reset function in particular. Useful for spot checking, but not bruteforcing, because it usually sends an email to a user and may lock the account until the password is reset. Too many of those usually alerts IT that something is going on.

Like someone else mentioned, I'm gonna list this as a vulnerability. If I get in using it, it goes in the report. If not, I'll tell the IT people but leave it out of the report. Lesser pentesters trying to find anything to add to a report will indeed flag it as a critical and blow it out of proportion.

The solution I commonly recommend is adding a threshold for total failed logins. Lockout does good on a per-user basis, so many failed logins over some time period. Add something else for someone trying a password across all users, like XX unique failed user logins over some time period. There's always some base level of noise, but a brute-force attack becomes really obvious quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common known issue. The best way to prevent this is showing a general message, like:

> If the entered username is known in our database, you will receive a new password in a couple of minutes.

This way the 'hackers' have no clue if the entered username is - indeed - in your database.

Comment: This was one of the suggestions put forward, I'm just trying to do more research on the matter. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, usernames are the public part, so I wouldn't worry too much. Another option is using a simple captcha and a not using JavaScript powered system. For example, one could use just a PHP powered form handler, using a form captcha, and checking the referrer to be the valid 'forgot password' page.

Comment: This is poor UX, as plenty of users will mistype or misremember their usernames.  Then they are faced with waiting around indefinitely wondering whether the email sending failed or got caught in a spam filter.  Since you have their email address on record, give them the option of providing their email address rather than their username.  You can then send them an email notifying them that they aren't registered with that email address so that they can take further steps to resolve their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this risk tends to be overstated when you get pen testers who are eager to add as many items to their reports as possible regardless of how useful they may be to the business.  Usernames are not traditionally considered secret, so enumerating them is not a big deal.

I've found that normally, the people claiming that this is a serious risk haven't really thought about all the ramifications.  They suggest things for the easy cases, like providing a less useful error message to the end-user when they fail to log in, but they miss the more difficult cases that require substantial changes to the application.  Registration, for instance – try registering with the username and you can determine if it's already registered or not.  There aren't quick and easy solutions to that that don't alter the UX substantially (although there are some mitigations listed in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69370/preventing-user-enumeration-on-registration-page)).

In this particular case, for this *specific* piece of functionality, you can ask for their email address, and send a "not found" email when they aren't registered.  This prevents enumeration *through this feature* while still being friendly to people who forget their username or which email address they registered with.  But chances are you are leaking usernames all over the place (e.g. through registration) and this is only the tip of the iceberg.  I think the risk/reward for this is low enough that this is the type of issue that should be pushed back on in most cases.  Usernames are not secret information – you've already got the password for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the input. Does give me some more things to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Generalization of message(s) is the best option as Jan has answered.

> If information provide by you matches our record, you will receive an
>   email with recovery information at a@b.c

The other thing you can do is to count the requests being generated for password recovery from same IP/session etc. and you can block for few minutes or hours if it is too frequent. You can go with the Captcha options also to reduce the rate of requests.